# Is it possible to load blazor pages (not components) from RCL without changing App.razor?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0

I am trying to create an blazor assembly that should be installed as a nuget package.
The idea is to load the blazor pages as if they where on an endpoint route, and this should be done by extension methods on startup.cs (net5)/ program.cs (net6) only.

The regular solution is to add AdditionalAssemblies on Router component inside App.razor.

```
<Router
    AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly"
    AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Component1).Assembly }">
    ...
</Router>
```

Is there a way to  achieve the same from an extension method called by startup.cs or program.cs?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you have the components in a Nuget package, why not just reference the package? That's what the package system is for. I'm not clear what your idea benefits any more.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something similar to Hangfire.
Just install the Nuget, configure at startup, and u are ready to go.
Some sort of plugin app to use in other apps

Comment: Still not really clear. Hangfire runs background jobs, nothing to do with Blazor. Maybe if you explain your use case it might help, but at the moment, I don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: like hangfire's dashboard I meant. You configure it by adding app.useHangfireDashboard(), which registers an endpoint "/hangfire" where you can control those background jobs. I need to do something similar, but with blazor.

Answer (score 2):

Check my repo, shows different ways to load RCL to a project, the only limitation today is to register dynamically a DI from the component library

https://github.com/elgransan/BlazorPluginComponents

I added an example for loading a RCL as a Page dynamically